# setting the height of each three divs to the hight of the last one/ the longest one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three floating to the left divs, with 33.33%, each with a different content. I want to make a height of each of them to be same. I thought of setting the height of the first two divs, that are shorter to the height of the last one with javascript. So that it will response to a screen device, and on mobile and tablets will not run.

The there divs will be displayed as a price table on the website. Any suggestions of how could I achieve it?

Comment: Is div content dynamic or fixed?

Comment: Use flexbox, equal height is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox`:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: You can check working demo here https://jsfiddle.net/h7at6dva/

Answer (score 0):

- Select all target elements using suitable selector.
- Get height(`.height()`) of all the elements in array using `.map`
- get Max height from the selected elements using `Math.max`
- Set the height of all the elements using `.height(NEW_HEIGHT)`

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var allH = $('.target').map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
  });
  var maxH = Math.max.apply(null, allH);
  $('.target').height(maxH);
});
```

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='target'>1
  <br>
</div>
<div class='target'>2
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class='target'>3
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>

<button>Set Max Height</button>
```

Comment: @MarcinKilarski Good luck mate...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I decided to use display:flex. Despite the fact that it is not supported by IE 9 and lower. I am sure that your answer is better, but I was looking for a simple solution. Thanks again.